# create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given?

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Following that has these fields:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

What I'm trying to create is a follow button that when pressed, gives the target a follower. Inside the view that has the follow button, has this logic:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'oauth/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_profile' # Without this, Django would default to request.user instead which is the logged in user

    def post(self, request, slug):
        follower = self.request.user

        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

        follow_unfollow(follower, self.object.id)  # Error is found inside this function
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

def follow_unfollow(follower, id):
    target = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)

    if follower.is_authenticated():
        if follower in target.followers.all():
            target.followers.delete(follower)

        else:
            target.followers.create(follower)  # Error outputs: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When we want to create a row for the new follower, an error happens saying that `create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass keyword arguments to `create()` method:

```
target.followers.create(follower=follower)
```

Or you can use `add()` method instead:

```
target.followers.add(follower)
```

Also it should be `remove` not `delete`:

```
target.followers.remove(follower)
```

Comment: For some reason when I do the add method, I get this error: `'Following' instance expected, got <SimpleLazyObject: <User: john>>` but when I use create, it works. Also, when I use remove I get an IDE error that says: `method remove does not exist on manager when foreign key does not allow nulls`

Comment: @user2896120 oh, sorry. `add()` will work only for normal manytomany field. To use `remove` try to add `null=True` to foreign keys: `target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this if statement isn't true even though it should be `if follower in target.followers.all():`

Comment: @user2896120 `target.followers` is `Following` instances. You need to chech `target.followers.filter(follower=follower)` as @Lemayzeur suggested.

Comment: I see it works correctly now, however, the page does not reload with the correct information after I click on the button, I have to reload it twice to see the updated results. This is because I am passing an outdated context object. I put the `self.get_object()` and `context` lines underneath the `follow_unfollow` method to get the updated context object, however, how do I get `self.object.id` for the `follow_unfollow` method without repeating code?

Comment: @user2896120 not sure but try to put context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object) after follow_unfollow line.

Comment: also, would you mind showing me the documentation for the `add()`, `remove()` functions? I couldn't find them while researching

Comment: @user2896120 sure, you can find this methods here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 2):

You missed some point in your view when you get the User instance, actually, you need to delete the `Following` instance in case it exists, try this:

```
def follow_unfollow(follower, id):
    target = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)

    if follower.is_authenticated():
        following = target.followers.filter(follower=follower)
        if following.exists():
            following.delete()
        else:
            # target.followers.create(follower=follower,target=target) 
            Following.objects.create(follower=follower,target=target)
```